# How to create a flow which detects consecutive value increments of another flow?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have a hot flow `fooFlow` that emits integer values. How can I construct another hot flow `barFlow` that only emits values when `fooFlow` emits a larger value than the most recent value emitted by `fooFlow`? In a sense, `barFlow` detects consecutive value increases of `fooFlow`.

**Example:** If `fooFlow` emits (4, 2, 7, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, ...), then `barFlow` emits (7, 2, 4, ...).

Comment: I updated my answer based on your updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a more natural or cleaner looking way to do this, but this is my first instinct:

```
val barFlow: SharedFlow<Int> = MutableSharedFlow<Int>().also { outflow ->
    var previousValue = Int.MAX_VALUE
    fooFlow.onEach { newValue ->
        if (newValue > previousValue) {
            outflow.emit(newValue)
        }
        previousValue = newValue
    }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is precisely what [`fold()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/fold.html) can be used for:

```
val barFlow = fooFlow.fold(Int.MIN_VALUE) { maxValue, newValue ->
  max(maxValue, newValue)
}
```

It lets you set a initial value (here, `Int.MIN_VALUE` so that every value is greater than it), then gives you access to the previous value (the `maxValue`) and the new value (the `newValue`), allowing you to do whatever comparisons and use that output as the newly emitted value.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but since the OP requested a hot flow, I think you would have to tag this with a `stateIn` or `shareIn` call to keep it hot.

Comment: @Tenfour04 - `fold` does not change a hot flow to a cold flow. It just mechanically transforms the flow as new values come in.

Comment: Oh, that's right. But it will simply return an Int, and only if the original SharedFlow is cancelled, right? You have it assigned to a local variable named `barFlow`.

Comment: Correct me as well if I'm wrong, but doesn't this flow emit the accumulated max value of `fooFlow`? I am rather looking for consecutive value increases of `fooFlow`. I have updated the OP to clarify this. @Tenfour04